# Is it expected behavior that MIN() window function in MariaDB/MySQL can return a non-null value from a window with only null values?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, window-functions

A minimal example for MariaDB (reproduced with with 10.2 and latest):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t
(
    id    int unsigned not null,
    value int unsigned null
);
INSERT INTO t
values (1, null);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v
as
select 1                 as id,
       ifnull(null, 999) as value
from t
;

select *,
       MIN(t.value) over (PARTITION BY t.id) as min_t,
       MIN(v.value) over (PARTITION BY t.id) as min_v
from t
         left join v
                   on t.id > v.id
;
```

It returns

```
id value id   value min_t min_v
1  null  null null  null  999
```

bit I would expect it to return

```
id value id   value min_t min_v
1  null  null null  null  null <-- null instead of 999
```

because there is only a single row and it has `value = null` in the window for `MIN` function. Sure, it is backed by a `ifnull()` in view's `select`, but the resulting set has `null` from a `left join` with no corresponding row, so it shouldn't be handled by `ifnull()` in the view, right?

Can this be considered a bug?

[MySQL sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7da5e/12) comparing **using a view** vs **using nested selects**. Nested selects produce the result I expect, using view doesn't.

Comparing to other RDBMS:

[Oracle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/18d8e/1): both ways work as I expect.

[PostgreSQL example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a1756/4): both ways work as I expect.

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: Have you tested with the latest version? Try  on dbfiddle.uk that has MYSQL 8 and Maria 10.4

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks for the suggestion. MySQL 8 works properly. MariaDB 10.3 has incorrect behavior, and MariaDB 10.4 (latest) just fails to execute the query. I ran the query in a MariaDB 10.4.12 docker container, and there is still incorrect behavior.

Comment: I suggest you should send a bug report to MariaDB list then. And feel free to self answer here that this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Reported this as a bug to MariaDB bug tracker:

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-21874